# Ошибка при попытке убрать слайдер swiper из мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, swiper, django-template

буду благодарна за помощь. Моя задача, чтобы слайдер swiper.js отображался только на декстопе,на мобильной версии сайта должны отображаться все карточки, которые в слайдере.На бекенде Phyton, шаблонизатор django рендерит карточки. Сейчас на мобильной версии отображается только одна первая карточка.В консоле ошибка main.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')
вот мой js

```
var swiperone;

    function resizeScrenn() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 857) {
            swiperone = new Swiper('.swiper', {
                direction: 'vertical',
                initialSlide: 1,
                loop: true,
                slidesPerView: 2,
                spaceBetween: 12,
                mousewheel: true,
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-unique',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-unique'
                },
                grabCursor: true,
            });
        }
        if (window.innerWidth < 857) {
            swiperone.destroy();
        }
    }

    resizeScrenn();

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        resizeScrenn();
    });
```

html

```
<div class = "swiper-container">
                        <div class = "swiper-button-prev-unique"></div>
                        <div class = "swiper-button-next-unique"></div>
                        <div class = "swiper swiper-master-card">
                            <div class = "wrapper-card-list swiper-wrapper">
                                {% for z in s.CityName_relate.all %}
                                    <div class = "wrapper-content-card swiper-slide">
                                        <div class = "wrapper-images">
                                            <img class = "image-card-content" src = "{% static "img/door_2.png" %}"
                                                 alt = "Изображение открытой двери">
                                            <div class = "indicator-content"></div>
                                            <div class = "wrapper-rating">
                                                {% if z.user_ratings_total == None %}
                                                    <span class = "card-rating">0</span><img class = "star-images"
                                                                                             src = "{% static "img/star.svg" %}">
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <span class = "card-rating">{{ z.user_ratings_total }}</span>
                                                    <img class = "star-images"
                                                         src = "{% static "img/star.svg" %}">

                                                {% endif %}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class = " content-card">
                                            <a class = "content-card__name"
                                               href = " https://{{ s.myCountry.nameCountry_for_sites_full }}/{{ request.default_lang }}/master/{{ s.myCity_base }}/{{ z.pk }}">{{ z.name|truncatewords:2 }}</a>

                                            <p class = "content-card__address">{{ z.formatted_address|truncatewords:6 }}</p>
                                            <div class = "content-card-inner-swiper">
                                                <p class = "content-card__review-main">Отзывы
                                                                                       ({{ z.post_relate.all.count }})</p>
                                                <a class = "content-card__phone-content"
                                                   href = "tel: {{ z.international_phone_number }}">{{ z.international_phone_number }}</a>
                                                <div class = "div-shaddow-content"></div>
                                                <button class = "content-card__text-content">Показать</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href = "tel: {{ z.international_phone_number }}"
                                           class = "card-button-content"
                                           type = "button"><img
                                                class = "card-button__img" src = "{% static "img/telephone_card.svg" %}"
                                                width = "27" height = "27"
                                                alt = "Кнопка позвонить"></a>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
```

Comment: поставьте проверку, если переменная `swiperone` не пустая

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что условие ставить перед   swiperone.destroy();?

Comment: добавила следующий код  if (window.innerWidth < 857) {
            if(swiperone){
                swiperone.destroy();
            }

        }   и ошибка в консоле на мобильной версии ушла, но по прежнему не работает swiperone.destroy(); Согласно документации должны убраться классы swiper.js на мобильной версии но этого не происходит

Comment: У вас Swiper инициализируется только при размере окна больше  857 `window.innerWidth > 857`. У вас на мобильной версии свайпер вообще не работает! Вы этого хотите?

Comment: да, я хочу чтобы он совсем не работал, а он работает, точнее классы его есть в мобильной  версии и мои карточки не отображаются все, а отображается только одна первая, остальные есть в коде html, но визуально расположены  как слайдер

Comment: Если вы хотите убрать классы с элементов, в html, то их надо убирать js кодом. Или наоборот, добавлять классы только при нужном размере окна. А у вас классы добавляются всегда.

Comment: А разве когда я указываю метод .destroy(),не должны убраться классы, которые добавляет swiper?

Comment: А у вас разве классы добавляются swiperом? Насколько вижу, классы добавляются на стороне сервера при генерации html.